# how to string.join object array parameters with customize output

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, join

I have an object like that

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; } 
    }
```

And I have `model` like `List<MyModel>`

```
    model[0]=new MyModel(){Key = 1,Value ="Something"};
    model[1]=new MyModel(){Key = 3,Value ="Something else"};
```

I want this output :

```
    1. Value is = Something //there is \n here
    3. Value is = Something else
```

So the seperator is `\n` and while `string.join(" \n ", ? )` what should I do?

Is that possible or not? I did it like that but I want to learn can I `string.join()` do that:

```
    var newArray = model.Select(x => ((x.Key)+". Value is ="+x.Value));
    string.join(" \n ",newArray );
```

Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Have you tried? Do you have any problems with result?

Comment: The method is called `string.Join()` not `string.join()`. And you should remove the space before `"\n"` in the separator. But other than that, your code seems to deliver your desired result.

Comment: `newArray` is poorly named: the result of Select is an IEnumerable, not an array

Comment: @Backs yes my solution is works fine but I wondering is the string.join can do that without pre custimization or linq

Comment: @CaiusJard tnx bro I will be atend next time

Answer (score 1):

```
var modelList = new List<MyModel>(){
        new MyModel(){ Key = 1, Value = "Value 1"},
        new MyModel(){ Key = 3, Value = "Value 2 with Key3"}
    };
    
    var stringArray = modelList.Select(model=> $"{model.Key}. Value={model.Value}");
    var finalString = String.Join('\n', stringArray);
    Console.Write(finalString);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/buCe8P

Comment: Isn't it same as my solution ? just different syntax in select

Comment: @BMErEr so yes. I just answered, because you asked. I have 10+ years of exp in C# and we often use String.Join() method. So "I want to learn can I string.join() do that" yes, you can, and it is the right way! The better solution would be `String.Join(Environment.NewLine, stringArray);` and much more better is using of `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

You did well. There are other ways but they are no more correct (in some cases at least).

Example with custom ToString method:

```
var all = string.Join("\n", model);
```

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"{Key}. Value Is: {Value}";
}
```

Or directly with project array:

```
var all = string.Concat(model.Select(x => $"{x.Key}. Value Is: {x.Value}\n"));
```

but there's an unnecessary line brake at the end.

Comment: Remove the \n from the ToString and do it via string.Join

Comment: adding the linebreak directly in the `ToString()` is a bad idea because, this way the consumer can't decide whether to have a linebreak or not. Why not using `string.Join()` and use linebreak as separator?